# Failed to start Docker Service.( Ubuntu 16.04 LTS)

Tags: docker-image

Job for docker.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status docker.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.

**systemctl status docker.service:**

```
● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead) (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2018-04-20 00:30:30 IST; 22s ago
     Docs: https://docs.docker.com
  Process: 16941 ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 16941 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Apr 20 00:30:30 cookie2 systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine.
Apr 20 00:30:30 cookie2 systemd[1]: docker.service: Unit entered failed state.
Apr 20 00:30:30 cookie2 systemd[1]: docker.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Apr 20 00:30:30 cookie2 systemd[1]: docker.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Apr 20 00:30:30 cookie2 systemd[1]: Stopped Docker Application Container Engine.
Apr 20 00:30:30 cookie2 systemd[1]: docker.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Apr 20 00:30:30 cookie2 systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine.
```

Comment: All I can say is uninstall and reinstall. Have you tried that?

Comment: Yes, I tried that also but It will not work and facing the same issue.

Comment: did you solve this problem?